# Удаление записей в xml (php)

Tags: xml, php, dom

Есть гостевая книга, которая хранит свои записи в xml
    `$dom = new DomDocument("1.0", "utf-8");

```
if(!file_exists(USERS_LOG)){
    $root = $dom->createElement("users");
    $dom->appendChild($root);
}else{
    $dom->load(USERS_LOG);
    $root = $dom->documentElement;
}
$n = $dom->createElement("name", $name);
$e = $dom->createElement("email", $email);
$m = $dom->createElement("msg", $msg);
$i = $dom->createElement("ip", $ip);
$d = $dom->createElement("datetime", $dt);
$user = $dom->createElement("user");
$user->appendChild($n);
$user->appendChild($e);
$user->appendChild($m);
$user->appendChild($i);
$user->appendChild($d);
$root->appendChild($user);
$dom->save(USERS_LOG);
header("location: gbook.php");
exit;`
```

а так же вот код их отображения (записей)

```
`$sxml = simplexml_load_file("users.xml");
$users = (array)$sxml; 
$users = array_reverse($users["user"]); 
foreach ($users as $item){
$dt = date("d-m-y H:i:s", $user->datetime*1);
$msg = nl2br($item->msg);
    echo "<hr>".$dt;
    echo "<h3> <a href='mailto:<?=$item->email?>'>".$item->name."</a></h3>";
    echo "<p><h4>".$msg."</h4></p>";    
}`
```

как сделать удаление записей или пометку на удаление, чтобы конретная запись не отображалась и возможно ли это

Comment: @kira, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще я советовал бы работать с XML средствами PHP, используя функцию

```
simplexml_load_file( $filename )
```

Она удобнее в получении данных их XML-Файла. А что по поводу удаления записи, то лучше просто генерировать XML-файл заново и потом перезаписывать его.

**Если надо удалять запись, то так:**

```
 <?php

$dom_xml = new DomDocument();
$dom_xml->loadXML('<car><model>volvo</model><model>Lada</model></car>');

$mod = $dom_xml->getElementsByTagName("model");

Foreach ($mod as $element) {
    if ($element->nodeValue == "Lada") {
        $del = $element->firstChild;
        $element->removeChild($del);
    }
}
echo $dom_xml->saveXML();

?>
```

Comment: а можно сделать не удаление записи, а как бы пометку, чтобы данное сообщение не отображалось в документе, чтобы не перезаписывать весь файл.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: begin
Пожалуйста();
end;
terminate;